# Pass thread arguments by reference gives me access violation

Tags: c++

I looked up how I can pass thread arguments by reference and I found `std::ref` so I used that:

```
void Watermarker::markDirectory(const std::string& targetDirectory, const std::string& watermarkPath)
{
    std::vector<std::thread*> threads;

    cv::Mat watermarkImage = loadImage(watermarkPath);
    if (watermarkImage.data == NULL) { return; }

    // Loop through all the files in the target directory
    for (const std::filesystem::path& path : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(targetDirectory))
    {
        std::thread* thread = new std::thread(mark, std::ref(targetDirectory), std::ref(path), std::ref(watermarkImage));
        threads.push_back(thread);
    }

    for (std::thread* thread : threads)
    {
        thread->join();
        delete thread;
    }
}
```

This is the function:

```
void Watermarker::mark(const std::string& targetDirectory, const std::filesystem::path& imagePath, cv::Mat& watermarkImage)
{
    cv::Mat image = loadImage(imagePath.string());
    if (image.data == NULL) { return; }

    cv::resize(watermarkImage, watermarkImage, image.size());

    // Give the images 4 channels
    cv::cvtColor(image, image, cv::COLOR_RGB2RGBA);
    cv::cvtColor(watermarkImage, watermarkImage, cv::COLOR_RGB2RGBA);

    // Add the watermark to the original image
    cv::addWeighted(watermarkImage, 0.3, image, 1, 0.0, image);

    saveImage(targetDirectory + "/watermarked_images/" + imagePath.filename().string(), image);
}
```

But when I run this it throws an exception "Access violation writing location. I get these 2 popups:
[image]

Without the `std::ref` and & in the function it works fine if I pass it by value, but I want it by reference.

Comment: We need to see more code please post a [mcve].  That said, are any of the values passed by reference going out of scope whilst the thread is executing ?

Comment: @RichardCritten updated the post

Comment: @TedLyngmo I receive the variables I try to pass by reference too:
```void Watermarker::markDirectory(const std::string& targetDirectory, const std::string& watermarkPath)```

Comment: All threads are accessing and writing to the _same_ `watermarkImage` when you pass ti by reference.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes, mark is a static function.

Comment: Suggestion: Use `std::list<std::thread> threads;` - `threads.emplace_back(mark, std::ref(targetDirectory), std::ref(path), std::ref(watermarkImage));` - `for(auto& th : threads) th.join();` instead. Much easier.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm when I change only that one to pass by value it still gives the same error

Comment: Unrelated note: If you are coming from C# or other languages where `list` is the go-to dynamic array, in C++ `list` is usually implemented as a doubly linked list and can be brutally slow. If you want a dynamic array, use `std::vector`.

Comment: @JelleVos You may have more bugs like that that we don't see (because, no [mre]), but that is a real bug. Change `cv::Mat& watermarkImage` into `const cv::Mat& temp_watermarkImage` and in the function, copy it `cv::Mat watermarkImage = temp_watermarkImage;`

Comment: When I only try to pss watermarkImage by value I still get the same error.

Comment: Pass it by `const&` and copy it in the function as I showed above - but as I also said, you may have undefined behavior in places in your code that we don't see because you haven't made a [mre]. Also, if you've fixed the bug we're talking about - update the code in the question to show it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks, thats it! The problem was indeed that I was changing the reference. Thank you very much! How can I mark your comment as the valid answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're changing `watermarkImage` from multiple threads at once in the `mark` function, making your program have undefined behavior.

Suggestion: Take it as a `const&` and copy it in the thread.

```
void Watermarker::mark(const std::string& targetDirectory,
                       const std::filesystem::path& imagePath,
                       const cv::Mat& temp_watermarkImage)   // const added
{
    cv::Mat watermarkImage = temp_watermarkImage;       // make a local copy
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `const cv::Mat& watermarkImage ... cv::Mat temp_watermarkImage = watermarkImage;` otherwise you have a naming conflict.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Almost. I did it the other way around to not have to change the rest of the function. I got it right in my comment under the question :-)

Answer (score 2):

I see a number of problems with your code.

- using `new` to create `std::thread` objects, just to `delete` them before exiting.  You don't need `new`/`delete` at all in this situation.
- inside your loop, `path` is a local variable that refers to a temporary `std::filesystem::path` object created by the `directory_iterator`.  That temporary will go out of scope and be destroyed when (depending on implementation) the current loop iteration is done, or the `directory_iterator` is destroyed when the loop is finished.  Either way, you are passing that `path` by reference into your `thread`s.  So the `thread`s are operating on `path` objects that *may* be destroyed before/while they are still running.  There is no good reason to pass a `std::filesystem::path` object by reference, it is lightweight enough to pass across thread boundaries by value with little overhead.  Your `thread`s need `path` objects that stay alive for the lifetime of the call to `mark()`.
- if `mark()` is a *non-static* method (and this code suggests that it is), then it has a hidden `this` parameter that you are not giving to each `thread` to pass into `mark()`, thus the `this` parameter (and all of the other parameters) will be corrupted when `mark()` is actually called.
- even if all the parameters were being passed properly, you are passing a reference to the same `watermarkImage` object to all of the `thread`s, and `mark()` is trying to manipulate that image without any synchronization across the `thread`s.

With that said, try something more like this instead:

```cpp
void Watermarker::markDirectory(const std::string& targetDirectory, const std::string& watermarkPath)
{
    cv::Mat watermarkImage = loadImage(watermarkPath);
    if (watermarkImage.data == NULL) { return; }

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    // Loop through all the files in the target directory
    for (const auto& path : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(targetDirectory))
    {
        threads.emplace_back(
            &Watermarker::mark, this,
            std::cref(targetDirectory), path, std::cref(watermarkImage)
        );
    }

    for (auto& thread : threads)
    {
        thread.join();
    }
}

void Watermarker::mark(const std::string& targetDirectory, const std::filesystem::path& imagePath, const cv::Mat& watermarkImage)
{
    cv::Mat image = loadImage(imagePath.string());
    if (image.data == NULL) { return; }

    cv::Mat new_watermarkImage = watermarkImage;
    cv::resize(my_watermarkImage, my_watermarkImage, image.size());

    // Give the images 4 channels
    cv::cvtColor(image, image, cv::COLOR_RGB2RGBA);
    cv::cvtColor(my_watermarkImage, my_watermarkImage, cv::COLOR_RGB2RGBA);

    // Add the watermark to the original image
    cv::addWeighted(my_watermarkImage, 0.3, image, 1, 0.0, image);

    saveImage(targetDirectory + "/watermarked_images/" + imagePath.filename().string(), image);
}
```